# python - how does split method work?

Tags: python, methods, split

Anyone knows how does the split function work in python? I mean, does it read the string char by char and then evaluates the code or it has another way of working? I've read the doc but it doesn't mention.

**EDIT**

For those who are curious like me, just check [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b76684d62a8d/Objects/stringlib/split.h). It should be on the 147th line as Chris stated.

Comment: Implementation is almost never given in documentation. That kind of defeats the point. If you're really curious, just go check out the source code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out the python source code (I used 2.7.1, but I doubt the location changed in the 3.x series), the full implementation can be found at `$src_dir/Objects/stringlib/split.h`. The function's name is `stringlib_split` and in 2.7.1 can be found on line 147.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking as of 3.2, there are several `split()` implementations. First of all, `split()` with no arguments has its own implementation, since it has slightly different semantics than other splits. When a split string is given, there are two possible implementations: one for a single character separator and one for other strings. The one character implementation simply scans through the string and appends chunks to a list. For longer strings, the algorithm is the same, but search performed with [Bloom filters](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: Does anyone know why there is a difference in implementation between the default and the one that takes a single character?  Specifically:
s = "1  2 3  4 5 6    ";

print(s.split())
# prints ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

print(s.split(' '))
# prints ['1', '', '2', '3', '', '4', '5', '6', '', '', '', '']